# "arguments" keyword in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
const add = (x=5, y=10) => console.log(x+y);
```

After we run the transpiler on this code, here is what the output would look like:

```
"use strict";
var add = function add() {
 var x = arguments.length <= 0 || arguments[0] === undefined ?
 5 : arguments[0];
 var y = arguments.length <= 1 || arguments[1] === undefined ?
 10 : arguments[1];
 return console.log(x + y);
};
```

I got this snippet from Learning react book.
I have two question here

> 1. Can arguments.length be negative?
> 2. Does checking the second "||" condition be sufficient to check whether arguments[0] or arguments[1] is undefined?

Comment: I don't understand the second question. Sufficient for what?

Comment: 1. No. 2. No. Why do you think so?

Comment: That's just defensive programming wrt to length being negative. It also enables short circuit evaluation.

Comment: Thank you @deceze, for checking whether argument is undefined.

Comment: @HenokTesfaye Yes you probably could, but JS engines don't like (read: don't optimise for) you to access `arguments` out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

> Can arguments.length be negative?

No. How could you call a function and put a negative number of things between `(` and `)`?!

> Does checking the second condition be sufficient?

No. The function might be called with only one argument.

Comment: Thank you @Quentin. Sorry for the 2nd question, I updated now.